# Open mapping theorem calculus proof via Banach-Schauder theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, alternative-proof, open-map

Can the following theorem from calculus:

> **Theorem:**
>   Let $F:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a continuously differentiable map, where $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain(Connected and open). If $\det (DF)\neq 0$ for all $x\in \Omega$, then  $F$ is an open map.

This is a classic theorem in calculus, but I was wondering whether it can be deduced given that we know the Banach-Schauder theorem?(Open mapping between Banach spaces)

Since differentiablity is essentially a linear approximation, and at each point the linear approximation is invertible and open, can such an argument be made?
I am aware that in this case there is a family of linear open surjective operators, but it seems to me that by a continuity of the differentials and a compactness argument , one can consider the worst linear approximation and show that open balls are sent to open balls.

I am however somewhat struggling in writing it down coherently, and would appreciate feedback.

Comment: As a remark, the Banach space open mapping theorem is total overkill for finite-dimensional spaces, the statement in the finite-dimensional case can be proven "directly". More concretely related to your question, the theorem you want to show should follow from the inverse function theorem (if $f:\Omega\to\Bbb R^m$ has invertible differential at some point $x$, then there is a neighbourhood of $f(x)$ admitting a smooth inverse of $f$), and I'm sure the inverse function theorem uses the fact that bijective matrices are invertible in order to construct the local inverse.

Comment: Also a notational remark: For me $DF$ is the differential of $F$, asking for $DF\neq 0$ is definitely not enough, what you want to ask is for $DF$ to have maximal rank (the statement is the simplest when $DF$ is invertible).

Comment: You are correct on it being an overkill and about $DF$. I was wondering whether one can use such logic to apply for say Gateaux derivatives and an appropriate open mapping theorem based on this logic.